# Fat/Thick lips/skin making endurance on oboe difficult?

Tags: oboe, embouchure

I have an observation leading to my question.... all top oboe players seem to have thin lips. I initial thought that playing the oboe might tone the facial muscles differently and cause thinner lips, but I think now after decades of on/off playing but initially intense for 5 years through university, perhaps it's that people with thinner lips have the advantage of not having extra (often substantial) cushioning that the embouchure muscles have to negotiate. They can therefore practise for longer and can feel confident playing for longer periods...and are therefore the ones that make it professionally.
I've come to this theory through observation, but also from wondering why I myself have very poor (15-30mins) endurance after YEARS of practise under a teacher and then professor teacher (who also had thin lips). I don't play on reeds that are too hard... just Soft- Medium soft European or Medium Soft - Medium American. But I wish I could play on a harder reed to get a bigger sound. I train my embouchure with an old reed when I don't practise on the instrument. When I tire, I feel my bottom teeth dig into the inside area of under my lower lip line. There is a substantial chunk of flesh there too as I have a thicker skin type in general. (Meaning I can't pinch my skin less than half and inch thick except at my elbow or top of hand.)
Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe your physiology is a factor - I wonder something similar about French horn. My personal journey with developing embouchure can be summarized by the quote “we are athletes of the small muscles”. By that I mean, it’s my belief that to gain playing endurance we have to train like athletes and get lots of rest and proper nutrition so our small muscles can develop to their maximum potential. So I really have to focus and train every day to get my mouth past any endurance plateaus. Just wanted to comment since I don’t have any expertise in this area - just a theory.